Does it hold that \sum_{i=1}^n X_i = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i in distribution if X_i = Y_i in distribution?
Does it hold that $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ in distribution if $X_i = Y_i$ in distribution for every $i = 1,2, \dots, n$? Not assuming independence or Gaussian necessarily. Having a hard time to prove this.
Edit: Totally didn't see the counter-example.
Would it be true if $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are greater than zero? Or what conditions need to hold for the sums to be equal in distribution?

If $X_1 = -X_2$ and $Y_1 = Y_2$, then, $X_1 + X_2 = 0$ and $Y_1 + Y_2 = 2Y_1$.

No. Take for instance $G$ a standard Gaussian variable and set $X_1=Y_1=Y_2=G$ and $X_2=-G$.

Nice counter example. Is there any necessary conditions for $X_i$ and $Y_i$ for the sum to be equally distributed? Is it true if $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are greater than zero?

The distribution of the sum depends on the multivariate joint distribution. So a sufficient condition would be to have that $(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ and $(Y_1,\cdots,Y_n)$ have the same distribution. That's for example the case if you consider independent random variables. The sign has little to do with it.

For an example with positive random variables, take $G $ uniform on $(-1,1)$, $X_1=Y_1=Y_2=2+G$ and $X_2=2-G$.
